# How to bind WPF OpenTok:VideoRenderer

Tags: wpf, data-binding, prism

i want to bind the following

```
public IVideoRenderer SubscriberVideo { get; set; }
```

to the

```
<OpenTok:VideoRenderer x:Name="SubscriberVideo" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="790" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="690" Margin="0,0,10.429,10.143" BorderBrush="#FF5B1919" BorderThickness="1">
<OpenTok:VideoRenderer.Effect>
<DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.6"/>
</OpenTok:VideoRenderer.Effect>
<OpenTok:VideoRenderer.Background>
<ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</OpenTok:VideoRenderer.Background>
</OpenTok:VideoRendere>
```

and im using **wpf mvvm**. anybody knows how to bind this?